# Why isn't #truncate including the given block as in the example?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

According to the documentation, #truncate can accept a block, but it is not including it!

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-truncate

```
2.0.0p247 :310 > helper.truncate("Once upon a time in a world far far away") { link_to "Continue", "#" }
 => "Once upon a time in a world..."
```

How do I include the block with truncate?

Rails 3.2.14.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the block part is new in rails 4.0.

http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/truncate

It looks like you would do this sort of thing

```
helper.truncate("Once upon a time in a world far far away", :omission => link_to("Continue", "#"))
```